# How to sum multiple columns in two data frames in r

Tags: r, join, merge

This question is similar to this one: [R: Sum column wise value of two/more data frames having same variables (column names) and take Date column as reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45752766/r-sum-column-wise-value-of-two-more-data-frames-having-same-variables-column-n) , but my dfs have different number of columns, columns names and there is not a specific reference column.

Modifying his example:

df1:

```
      V1  V2  V3  
       2   4   5   
       3   5   7
```

df2:

```
      V1  V5  V2  V4   
       2   4  4   5   
       3   0  5   7
```

I want the result as:

df3:

```
      V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
       4   8   5   5   4
       6  10   7   7   0
```

I keep getting errors like:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
✖ Input `..1` can't be recycled to size 28. # 28 because this is referring to my df
ℹ Input `..1` is `colnames(col_name)`.
ℹ Input `..1` must be size 28 or 1, not 5992.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I've tried with merge, join, by ...etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a base R option :

```
tmp <- cbind(df1, df2)
data.frame(sapply(split.default(tmp, names(tmp)), rowSums))

#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  4  8  5  5  4
#2  6 10  7  7  0
```

**data**

```
df1 < -structure(list(V1 = 2:3, V2 = 4:5, V3 = c(5L, 7L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df2 <- structure(list(V1 = 2:3, V5 = c(4L, 0L), V2 = 4:5, V4 = c(5L, 
7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```